# onChange event for calculation in dynamic grid updates wrong rows - Classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have an old ASP site that needs a change.  I need a basic grid to set pricing.
I want to enter a price in one column and have it display text of "Debit" or "Credit" in another column based on positive or negative input. I also want to calculate the extended price based on qty. I've just started with the first (text display) one for now, and can't get it to work.

The grid could have n number of rows based on the data set returned so I have a counter which I concatenate to the input IDs to indicate the row number.  The counter is working fine and I can see the id's increment correctly. I've tried to pass the correct input value and id but when the function fires it updates the wrong rows. Actually it updates all the rows below the row I've changed. I have spent WAY too much time banging my head on what I thought would be a 15 min issue.  Need a few more pairs of eyes.

```
<script>
    function myFunction(val) {

        data_length = document.getElementById("datalength").value;
        i = 0;
        while(i++ < data_length)               

            if (val > 0) {
                document.getElementById("chargepay" +i).innerHTML = "Credit";

            }
            else 
            { 
                document.getElementById("chargepay" +i).innerHTML = "Debit";
            }      
        }
</script>
```

Here is the row in the grid loop that has the input field to pass the amount value:

```
<td align="center"><input id="AMNT<%=count%>" size="10" name="AMNT" 
onchange="myFunction(this.value)"/></td>
```

Here is the row in the grid to display the update from the onchange

```
<td align="center"><p id="chargepay<%=count%>"</p>td>
```

When I update the value in the input box in first row, it updates all rows below but not that row. I have a loop, I think. I only want it to update one row at a time as I change the values.

Any help / direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide a JSFiddle with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't included you need to include the JQuery library from local system or CDN.

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
```

You need to add the change even for every input involved in your mathematical calculation. Here 'this; is passed as argument, so that we can find the parent row(through which all other controls contained in it can be searched.

```
onchange="myFunction(this)"
```

Inside the function 'myFunction', We at first finds the closest/parent 'tr'.
Again we selects the input field corresponding to Quantity, Amount etc(you can add more if required). The selection can be based on Id, Name, Class etc

```
var qty = currentRow.find('input[name=QTY]').val();
            //or (id starting with 'QTY')

var qty = currentRow.find('input[id*=QTY]').val();
            //or (give any class name and replace it instead of 'class-name')

var qty = currentRow.find('input.class-name').val();
```

We need to convert the string value to float to perform accurate mathematical calculations. While parsing empty string we may end up with 'NAN' - Not a Number. So we need to check before parsing.

```
qty = (qty == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(qty));
```

After all this you can use this value for any math calculation and setting it as text of the

tag or any other.
If its p, div, span you need to set it as 'text'

```
currentRow.find('input[name=TOT]').text(totalAmount);
```

And if its input you need to set it as 'value'

```
currentRow.find('p[name=TOT]').val(totalAmount);
```

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  var currentRow = $(elem).closest('tr');
  var qty = currentRow.find('input[name=QTY]').val();
  var amt = currentRow.find('input[name=AMNT]').val();
  qty = (qty == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(qty));
  amt = (amt == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(amt));
  var totalAmount = qty * amt;
  currentRow.find('p[name=TOT]').text(totalAmount);
  currentRow.find('p[name=TYPE]').text(totalAmount > 0 ? 'Credit' : 'Debit');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="QTY1" size="10" name="QTY" onchange="myFunction(this)" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="AMNT1" size="10" name="AMNT" onchange="myFunction(this)" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <p id="TOT1" name="TOT"></p>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <p id="chargepay1" name="TYPE"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="QTY2" size="10" name="QTY" onchange="myFunction(this)" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="AMNT2" size="10" name="AMNT" onchange="myFunction(this)" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <p id="TOT2" name="TOT"></p>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <p id="chargepay2" name="TYPE"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="QTY3" size="10" name="QTY" onchange="myFunction(this)" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input id="AMNT3" size="10" name="AMNT" onchange="myFunction(this)" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <p id="TOT3" name="TOT"></p>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <p id="chargepay3" name="TYPE"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is working for the text display.   Unfortunately I'm even less familiar with Jquery .
Could I use ii to also "do the math" for my price * qty = ext price requirement with same looping grid / id situation? 
Can you point me in the direction of a good function / suntax reference?

Comment: @mham99 : Yes, If all your fields come in same row you can easily do that. I've updated my answer

Comment: still, if this is not your requirement, Please update your question with the JsFiddle or code snippet, Using this code with required modification or a new fiddle, so that someone with better approaches can help you.